# 3d plot using data array (x, y, z) in Qt

Tags: arrays, qt, plot

I am working on a GUI that will show the 3D plot from a continuously incoming data array of (x, y, z). I have search around but cannot really find a solution of that. If you have any idea or any example for that, please advise. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in native Qt. I'd suggest the [QwtPlot3D](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/) library which is an extension for Qt and is easy so implement in existing Qt projects.

However, I have no experience in whether it works well with newer Qt versions (>=5)

Comment: I have checked  QwtPlot3D library before and found some possible function: bool   loadFromData(Qwt3D::Triple **data, unsigned int columns, unsigned int rows, bool uperiodic=false, bool vperiodic=false) and bool   loadFromData(Qwt3D::TripleField const &data, Qwt3D::CellField const &poly). However I don't really know what value to put for the input.